# Not receiving Toast Notifications. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: notifications, windows-8.1-preview

It's been about two weeks since upgrading to the Windows 8.1 Preview, and I haven't gotten a single toast from an app. There have been many restarts, and everything is up to date as far as Windows Update and the Store are concerned.

I used to get toasts from email, calendar, messaging, Skype, Xbox Live, etc. but I never get anything now, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

I've tested email by making sure the program was running in the background and sending myself an email from a different address via webmail. I was never notified.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure toast notifications didn't get turned off somehow for all apps during the upgrade?

Comment: @Karan I'm not sure how to check. The apps don't seem to have any related settings. The closest thing I can find is just the global Notifications setting in the Charms menu. But the only options are to mute notifications for x amount of time.

Comment: @Karan It was already enabled, but after toggling that, I'm getting mail notifications again. Seems to be working!

Comment: Good to know! I added it as an answer below for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to `Settings charm / Change PC settings / Search & apps / Notifications` and enable toast notifications for the relevant apps (toggle the setting if already enabled):

[image: 1]

Comment: Great, thanks! It's been relocated to a new category "Search & apps" as seen here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FRUZ9.png

Answer (score 0):

> **To change which notifications appear here**
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Settings.)
> 2. Tap or click Change PC settings, tap or click Search and apps, and then Notifications.
> 3. Under Show notifications from these apps, set the app you want to On or Off.
>
> **To hide notifications temporarily in this area**
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Settings.)
> 2. Tap or click Change PC settings, tap or click Search and apps, and then Notifications.
> 3. Turn on Quiet hours and choose how long you want notifications hidden.
> 4. If you want to turn them back on before the time period is over, turn off Quiet hours.
>
> **To change notifications for a specific account**
>
> Mail lets you manage notifications for each account. Here's how:
>
> 1. On Start, tap or click Mail.
> 2. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and then click Settings.)
> 3. Tap or click Accounts.
> 4. Choose the account you want to change notifications for.
> 5. Under Show email notifications, tap or click the option you want.

source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/how-manage-notifications

I tried other methods found on the internet but this one worked for me.